# Why content won't take a different background color?

Tags: html, css

I have the whole page set to gray as the background color, but would like only the content area to be set to a different color. According to my CSS, this should be happening but it isn't. Why not?

```
html,
body {
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
}

#page-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 1024px;
}

#content {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

OK, well, I thought there might be an obvious answer, because this is a severly slimmed-down version of my code. Yes it has content and there are things in the page-wrapper.

The jsfiddle link is here: http://jsfiddle.net/2pzo80Lu/

Also, if anyone has critiques of the code otherwise, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post your HTML. And in cases like these a jsFiddle.net example is often useful.

Comment: Does it have any content? Try adding a height to your #page-wrapper

Comment: You need to post your html or provide more detail since your posted code looks like it should work http://jsfiddle.net/s79zyexw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `overflow:auto` to your rules for #content because the children are floated. Floating them essentailly removes them from the normal flow and collapses the parent since it behaves as if there's no content. Adding the overflow rule restores the behavior you seek.

```
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2pzo80Lu/1/)**

Comment: I do actually remember reading about this. It did fix part of the problem, but then the blue stops about halfway down the content. Any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Because of the way you used absolute positioning on some of the child elements.

Comment: So what is the workaround for this then? Just avoid absolute positioning altogether? Is there another way besides that?

Comment: Well there's a variety of ways to layout content so I can't tell you how to do that, just that the absolute positioning is causing the issue in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

your elements inside #content div is floated right and left so the div has no height ( `0px` ) , you can solve this in css by adding the following code

```
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

or in html by adding the following code before the close of the element of #content

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

this will clear any floating and you code should work very will. good luck